# How do I get all changed file names between HEAD and Staging Area in git

Tags: git

Rename a file `foo.txt` to `bar.txt`, then git add. I would like to get all changed file paths. Since it's a rename we are technically changing two file paths:

```
foo.txt
bar.txt
```

### What I've tried

`git diff --name-only` -- only gives `bar.txt`

`git diff --name-only HEAD...` gives nothing because the `...` syntax just puts head at the end.

`git diff --name-only ...HEAD` gives nothing.

### Here's how to do it if I commit my changes (but that's not the question here)

`git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD` -- will spit out `bar.txt` but requires two commit hashes. My changes are not committed, so I don't have a hash.

`git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1` -- will spit out `foo.txt` but requires two commit hashes. My changes are not committed, so I don't have a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name-only just shows you the current (or last, for deleted) names of affected files. If you want more details on what happened to them,

```
git diff --name-status @
```

Since you `git added` the rename, it's already in your index, the remaining difference is from your checked out commit `@` aka `HEAD`.

You could also `git diff --name-status --cached @` to show any changes in  what you've added, ignoring the work tree.